# Weird white space issue in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is supposed to display a file input and a submit input.
This is fine, however I keep receiving an unwanted empty line at the bottom.

Photo of issue:
[image]

Here is the HTML code for my div:

```
    <div id="change_pp"> 
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="pp_file"/>
<input type="submit" name="pp_submit" value="Upload Photo"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    #change_pp
{
background:#f9f9f9;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
border-left: 1px dashed #ccc;
border-right: 1px dashed #ccc;
width:18%;
margin-left:3.5%;
padding:0;
}

#change_pp input[type=file]
{
width:100%;
}
```

Also, here is a Fiddle with my entire CSS, to show that my previous CSS is not effecting this https://jsfiddle.net/bmp3my4c/

As you can tell, the Fiddle works fine and the code should work fine, however in all major browsers I am receiving the unwanted white space.

- NOTE: I know the fiddle is working properly, in the browser the div is still appearing with the white space though. That is the weird part.

Comment: There is no white space in your fiddle, nor if I just copy and paste your HTML and CSS

Comment: Sure, but on my website there is a white space, that is the issue. That is the weird thing, it works fine in the fiddle.

Comment: Which means that you must have other conflicting CSS rules, likely a `margin` on the `input` or `padding` on the container `div`, which is causing the problem.  Have you tried to inspect element in Chrome (or similar)?

Comment: Yes I have, also, the Fiddle contains my entire CSS.

Comment: Does it help if you actually include `html`, `body` and `doctype` tags? Like JoeP said, the issue isn't here, we can't see it. If we can't see it, we can't help it.

Comment: OK I see the issue, see my answer below.

Comment: @somethinghere adding the `html` and `body` tag did cause the problem, without them the browser was not inheriting the default rule for forms which was to have `margin-bottom: 1em`

Comment: Did you have a doctype? I'm betting you don't.

Comment: @Rob I did not, how do you know?

Comment: Because that would cause the problem.

Comment: @Rob good spot.  This is really the answer to be honest.

Comment: Very interesting... How so?

Comment: I added an answer to explain further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a doctype based on your comment. This is what is causing the problem. Add a proper doctype, `<!DOCTYPE html>` on your very first line and the problem will go away without modifying what you originally had.

All modern web pages are required to have a doctype. Without one, you are in quirks mode and using an incorrect box model. Add the doctype to be put into standards mode.

Comment: Ahh, this helped, however this caused an issue with my php `session_start()`, do you know how to add the DOCTYPE at the very beginning and to still be able to use `session_start()` without an error?

Comment: @StanRogers That would be a question for a new topic.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS rule and it should solve the problem:

```
form {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Edit: As Rob pointed out, this fixed the issue but was not the cause of the problem.  The issue was a missing Doctype, as shown in his answer.